# ListView receives touches, but onItemClickListener does not receive clicks after a pause and resume

Tags: android, listview, onresume, onpause

We generate several ListViews that hold info for a user to filter information in another fragment. It works fine, unless you pause and resume the app (say, backgrounding it, or locking the screen). Once you do that, the list can be scrolled, but not clicked.

List generating code:

```
private View addList(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, final FilterValue.SearchCategory type, final String[] labels) {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = generateArrayAdapter(inflater, labels, type);
    if(adapter == null) {
        return null;
    }
    filterAdapters.add(adapter);

    ListView list = (ListView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.on_demand_filter_list, container, false);

    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    list.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
    list.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            LOG.d(TAG, "NO TOUCHING!");
            return false;  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    });
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            LOG.d(TAG, "onItemClick!");
            CheckedTextView textView = (CheckedTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            textView.toggle();
            if (textView.isChecked()) {
                filterValue.addToSelectedList(labels[i], type);
            } else {
                filterValue.removeFromSelectedList(labels[i], type);
            }
        }
    });
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    filterListContainer.addView(list);

    return list;
}
```

The onTouch listener only exists to ensure the Touch is received. (It is.) The DescendantFocusability appears to have no effect, this bug exists before and after it was added.

Each is tied to a button that shows or hides the list.

```
    titleHeader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View clickedView) {
            closeNetworkList();
            closeGenreList();
            titlesOpen = !titlesOpen;
            ImageView indicator = (ImageView) clickedView.findViewById(R.id.filter_expansion_indicator_icon);
            if (indicator != null) {
                if (titlesOpen) {
                    indicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_filter_up);
                } else {
                    indicator.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_filter_down);
                }
            }
            if (titlesOpen) {
                titlesListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                titlesListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
```

Tapping this button to hide and then show the listView (which was generated with addList) resets something, and the items can be clicked again.

XML for an item row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:focusable="false"
          android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
          android:padding="8dp"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

<CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@drawable/on_demand_filter_checked_text_sel"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="76dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/checkbox_sel"
        android:drawablePadding="14dp"
        style="@style/LargeRegular"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The focusables are new additions, but neither worked. The problem occurred before they were added.

The ListView itself:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/list"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="275dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
      android:divider="@color/Transparent"
      android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
      android:cacheColorHint="#ffffff"/>
```

I am at my absolute wits' end. No one on my team has a sensible solution to this. It works fine, right up until you pause and resume. We do absolutely nothing that touches the views in resume or pause. Can anyone help? I can provide more detail as needed.

Comment: And have you tried to comment out your pause/resume callbacks to see whether they do not affect this list view?

Comment: Yes. Resume has no callbacks, and the only one in pause had no effect.

Comment: Moving our OnItemClickListener code into individual OnClickListeners generated in the individual list items' getView() calls makes this problem go away. While this is an acceptable workaround, it's interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with my app (extended SurfaceView which lost touch events after resume) and resolved it by calling the setFocusable( true ) in the onResume() implementation. Apparently the view didn't get the focus and therefore did not receive the touch events. Not sure whether this is the case here, but worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

Remembered that I had had a similar problem with fragment activities. I had a case when layout requests were blocked, they did not cause actual layout traverse.
I've fixed it in [Enroscar library](http://code.google.com/p/enroscar) ([BaseFragment](http://code.google.com/p/enroscar/source/browse/trunk/eclipse-project/src/com/stanfy/app/BaseFragment.java) class) with the following snippet of code in a fragment class:

```
@Override
  public void onStart() {
    // ... other staff ...
    super.onStart();
    /*
      XXX I don't know the reason but sometimes after coming back here from other activity all layout requests are blocked. :(
      It looks like some concurrency issue or a views tree traversal bug
     */
    final View contentView = getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    if (contentView != null) {
      final ViewParent root = contentView.getParent();
      if (contentView.isLayoutRequested() && !root.isLayoutRequested()) {
        if (DebugFlags.DEBUG_GUI) { Log.i("View", "fix layout request"); }
        root.requestLayout();
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Tried it, and that's not quite it either. How did you debug this sort of thing? It's puzzling to figure out what's happening, short of overriding the entire class to have it spit debug statements for every call the ListView could possibly make.

Comment: Used Android sources and Eclipse debugging. If you have sources that correspond to emulator's API level it's much easier to debug.